# Autoplay music on chrome

Tags: javascript, autoplay

I have found only deprecated anwers so i need to ask how to make autoplay on chrome?

```
<audio autoplay loop controls src="./audio/menu.wav" data-start-screen-audio></audio>

let music = new Audio("./audio/menu.wav");
music.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
    music.play();
});
```

these two metods works on other browsers but on chrome not, how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

by default in modern browser, this is not allowed but if you add the `muted` attribute it will work fine

as they mention here in [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-autoplay)

> Note: Sites that automatically play audio (or videos with an audio track) can be an unpleasant experience for users, so should be avoided when possible. If you must offer autoplay functionality, you should make it opt-in (requiring a user to specifically enable it). However, this can be useful when creating media elements whose source will be set at a later time, under user control.

but in the case of media content you could run the `play` action from `js`
like this

```
<video src="" id="videoEl">

document.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('videoEL').play()
}
```

for more info check the [`autoplay guide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)

Comment: It is an error: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first

Comment: there is another way you could add `muted autoplay` but after the page loads remove the `muted` attribute

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use (.autoplay = true;) as following (tested on Chrome Desktop):

```
<audio id="audioID" loop> <source src="path/audio.mp3"  type="audio/mp3"></audio>
    
<script>
    var myaudio = document.getElementById("audioID").autoplay = true;
</script>
```

Comment: The same result as above ;/

Comment: What's your chrome version? This isn't ought to work because chrome changed their [policy regarding autoplay](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes). On a different note, don't do this. The number of users who want their browser to start playing audio out of nowhere is exactly zero

Comment: the latest, i think i can make an exception in this case because it is a game